# Wrong monitor resolution in Catalina

Tags: macos, display, catalina, resolution

After update from Mojave to Catalina one of my external displays determined by system with the wrong native resolution. I use Samsung C43J890DK which is have resolution 3840x1200 pix. But Catalina determinate 1920x600 as native resolution for this monitor. I scale it to 3840x1200 from system preferences, but every boot or exit from sleep mode, system resizes resolution 3840x1200 (got it from NVRAM) -> 1920x600 (because Catalina think this is native resolution for monitor) -> 3840x1200 (after resizing by system). As result, all opened windows scaled to 1920x600 pix.

I tryed to disable HiDPI, but this not help. All what i can do, its return standard preferences with frequency and resolution selection using IOGFlags.  How i can change native resolution for this monitor to  3840x1200?

```
Contents of /System/Library/Displays/Contents/Resources/Overrides/DisplayVendorID-4c2d/DisplayProductID-f5b

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">

<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>DisplayIsTV</key>
<false/>

<key>DisplayProductID</key>
<integer>3931</integer>

<key>DisplayProductName</key>
<string>GNUSMAS C43J890DKI</string>

<key>DisplayVendorID</key>
<integer>19501</integer>

<key>IOGFlags</key>
<integer>3</integer>

<key>default-resolution</key>
<data>
AAAPAAAABLAAeAAA
</data>

<key>dspc</key>
<array>
    <data>
    jOkAUPCwR0AIIJgMAAAAAAAa
    </data>
</array>

<key>scale-resolutions</key>
<array>
    <data>
    AAAPAAAABLAAeAAA
    </data>
</array>
```

My ioreg for this display

```
| |   | | +-o display0  <class IODisplayConnect, id 0x100002a5e, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (0 ms), retain 6>
| |   | |         "IOProviderClass" = "IODisplayConnect"
| |   | |         "IODisplayEDID" = <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>
| |   | |         "IODisplayPrefsKey" = "IOService:/AppleACPIPlatformExpert/PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/IGPU@2/AppleIntelFramebuffer@0/display0/AppleDisplay-4c2d-f5b"
| |   | |         "IODisplayParameters" = {"bgsc"={"min"=0,"max"=65536,"value"=65536},"pscn"={"min"=8800,"max"=10000,"value"=10000},"rgsc"={"min"=0,"max"=65536,"value"=65536},"cmod"={"min"=0,"max"=4096,"value"=1},"ggsc"={"min"=0,"max"=65536,"value"=65536},"cyuv"={"min"=0,"max"=268435456,"value"=268435456},"vblm"={"min"=0,"max"=196608,"value"=65536},"ownr"=4294968793,"colr"={"min"=0,"max"=18446744073709551615,"value"=257}}
| |   | |         "IODisplayAttributes" = {"IODisplayAttributes"=<676174760000000073676c6603000000726c6f63010000006364670080808000676c666401000000>}
| |   | |         "IODisplayConnectFlags" = <00000000>
| |   | | |   "IODisplayParameters" = "IOFramebufferParameterHandler is not serializable"
| |   | | |       "IOMatchCategory" = "IODisplayParameters"
| |   | | |   "IODisplayParameters" = "IOFramebufferParameterHandler is not serializable"
| |   | | |       "IOMatchCategory" = "IODisplayParameters"
```